# Razor Pages, GET method and OnGet handler work in local but not work in web server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, razor-pages, getmethod

I have a small ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project.
I have 1 page handlers:

```
    public int XId { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int Did)
    {
        XId = Did;
        return Page();
    }
```

and in my .cshtml file:

```
<span>@Model.XId</span>
```

in localhost everything is ok.
for example https://localhost:44320/Home/bb?Did=4 will show 4
but in web server it is always 0
it seams that parameter is 0
what is the problem?

I upload this site to another sever and it work fine!
is that problem relate to iis configuration?

Comment: How did you set the route?And Since you considered it was caused by iis configuration,it may help if you could show your iis configuration related

Comment: You could try to set XId with a value such1or 2,and observe the value in web server, if it changed with your setting,I think your error may related with the document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/iis-urlrewrite-middleware-query-strings-are-preserved

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the CDN configuration and after reset CDN, every things ok.